# How can I edit my code to print out the content of my created json file?

Tags: python, json

My program takes a csv file as input and writes it as an output file in json format. On the final line, I use the print command to output the contents of the json format file to the screen. However, it does not print out the json file contents and I don't understand why.

Here is my code that I have so far:

```
import csv 
import json

def jsonformat(infile,outfile):
    contents = {}
    csvfile = open(infile, 'r')
    reader = csvfile.read()

    for m in reader:
        key = m['No']
        contents[key] = m
    
    jsonfile = open(outfile, 'w')
    jsonfile.write(json.dumps(contents))

    csvfile.close()
    jsonfile.close()
    return jsonfile

infile = 'orders.csv'
outfile = 'orders.json'

output = jsonformat(infile,outfile)

print(output)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your function returns the `jsonfile` variable, which is a file.
Try adding this:

```
jsonfile.close()
with open(outfile, 'r') as file:
    return file.read()
```

Comment: I added that code to the line after jsonfile.close(), but it now prints out an empty bracket : {}.

Comment: Probably that's because your file is empty

Comment: It is at first, but I am trying to create a json file from the csv file within the program. So basically, I am trying to write the empty json file to have the contents of the csv file.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that the problem is with the for loop, in particular in the m variable. Here's late at night so that I don't have time to solve your problem, but you should check those three lines and the Pranav's answer.

Answer (score 0):

Your function returns a file handle to the file `jsonfile` that you then print. Instead, return the *contents* that you wrote to that file. Since you opened the file in `w` mode, any previous contents are removed before writing the new contents, so the contents of your file are going to be whatever you just wrote to it.

In your function, do:

```
def jsonformat(infile,outfile):

    ...

    # Instead of this:
    # jsonfile.write(json.dumps(contents))


    # do this:
    json_contents = json.dumps(contents, indent=4) # indent=4 to pretty-print
    jsonfile.write(json_contents)

    ...

    return json_contents
```

---

Aside from that, you aren't reading the CSV file the correct way. If your file has a header, you can use `csv.DictReader` to read each row as a dictionary. Then, you'll be able to use `for m in reader: key = m['No']`. Change `reader = csvfile.read()` to `reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)`

As of now, `reader` is a string that contains all the contents of your file. `for m in reader` makes `m` each character in this string, and you cannot access the `"No"` key on a character.

Comment: I made the change you suggested, but it returns an empty curly brace with no data.

Comment: Edit your question to provide an example of your input file. I suspect it is empty. Even once you fix that, `reader` will be a string and `for m in reader:
        key = m['No']` will throw an error. @Geraldo

Comment: It wasn't empty before, but now that I check, the csv file is empty. I don't know how that happened. It won't let me delete the file either. How do I close if from python so that I can delete the file?

Answer (score -1):

```py
a_file = open("sample.json", "r")
a_json = json.load(a_file)
pretty_json = json.dumps(a_json, indent=4)
a_file.close()

print(pretty_json)
```

Using this sample to print the contents of your json file. Have a good day.